# trying to send xlsx with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, mime

Im trying to send an email with a xlsx file attached to it, i made/formatted the xlsx with xlsxwriter, everytime i send it with my code, the xlsx loses all the formatting / colors / functions added by my other code.

```py
from string import Template
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

MY_ADDRESS = 'myemail'

def get_contacts(filename):
    names = []
    emails = []
    with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
        for a_contact in contacts_file:
            names.append(a_contact.split()[0])
            emails.append(a_contact.split()[1])
    return names, emails



def read_template(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as template_file:
        template_file_content = template_file.read()
    return Template(template_file_content)


def main():
    names, emails = get_contacts('mycontacts.txt') # read contacts
    message_template = read_template('message.txt')

    # set up the SMTP server
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='my.smpt.server')
#    s.starttls()
    #s.login(MY_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)

    # For each contact, send the email:
    for name, email in zip(names, emails):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()       # create a message

        # add in the actual person name to the message template
        message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title())

        # Prints out the message body for our sake
        print(message)

        # setup the parameters of the message
        msg['From']=MY_ADDRESS
        msg['To']=email
        msg['Subject']="This is TEST"

        # add in the message body
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))


        part = MIMEBase('application', "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        part.set_payload(open("my_filename.xlsx", "rb").read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="my_filename.xlsx"')
        msg.attach(part)

        # send the message via the server set up earlier.
        s.send_message(msg)
        del msg

    # Terminate the SMTP session and close the connection
    s.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried searching alot and it works for everyone but for me, maybe the problem is that im formatting my file with xlsx.
Also when i send the file via bash using the command mail, the file keep all the formatting

Comment: it cant be it, since when i send it with the mail command in bash it works just fine...